# Enabling PHP not working after enabling on OSX Lion

Tags: php, apache, osx-lion

I have followed several tutorials. Web sharing is on and I uncommented the php module in apache2/httpd.conf, but when I try to open the phpinfo file, it still tries to open it as a file.

Comment: What steps did you take and how did you try to open the file?

Comment: I added it to the root of my personal website and tried to open it in Firefox.

Comment: Does "the phpinfo file" have ".php" at the end of the filename? What does "the phpinfo file" have in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get php working on Mac OS X Lion 10.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790568/how-do-you-get-php-working-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7)

Comment: I also struggled with getting php/apache to work on lion.. then I found MAMP, this is just awesome for web development: http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html  very simple to set up and works like a charm.

Comment: Yes the info file has php at the end and I've also tried other php files.

Comment: The actual answer which is working is here. This appears to be case when you update your Mac OSX: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211015/el-capitan-apache-error-message-ah00526

Answer (score 31):

Edit your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and make sure the line:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

...exists. I think it's commented out by default in the standard OS X config, but from what I remember, you just need to uncomment it, then re-start Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

And you should be good to go.

OR

use `MAMP`

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: are you loading your PHP files from your Home folder Sites directory?

Comment: If you mean Username/Sites, then yes.

Comment: If rebooting the machine does not help.. use MAMP it's free.

Comment: The Apache/PHP installation that comes with the Mac works fine; MAMP is not necessary.

Comment: I would rather not have to use applications that I don't need.

Comment: OK, I installed MAMP and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Shouldn't the link to my site be http://myip/~Username/ instead of http://10.0.0.5/~Username/?

Comment: Figured it out. When I change 10.0.0.5 to localhost in my browser it works. Anybody know how I can configure it to allow me to open php files without having to open from my browser?

Comment: I had to do `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` as Mark said in his comment

Comment: saved me at least an hour.
was near to slap some people in a fece.

Comment: for php7 : LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

Answer (score 24):

Make sure your Apache config includes this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: On my system it is in a file named php5.conf, but I am using Apache from MacPorts instead of the original... I think I copied my config directly from the original config, though

Comment: You may have to copy /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini if the latter does not exist.

Comment: you can directly add this line within `<IfModule mime_module> </IfModule>` block