# I can't get php working on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: php, apache, osx-lion

I've been struggling to get PHP up and running on my Mac. I have followed all the instructions on the previous discussion on this topic ([How do you get php working on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790568/how-do-you-get-php-working-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7/15711716#15711716?newreg=c4c9d976438e430599fc73f47bc746ab)) and it's still not working. When trying to open a .php file it displays it as the source code and doesn't even seem to recognise it as a PHP file, but calls it **TextWrangler document** instead.

In my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file I have done the following:

- taken off the # in front of the `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`
- changed User to my username
- changed the `DirectoryIndex` to `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm`
- changed `DocumentRoot` to `/Users/myusername/Sites/`
- changed `Directory` to `<Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">`
- restarted Apache numerous times
- switched web Sharing on and off
- changed php.ini.default to php.ini

Still not working. Can you help?

Comment: did you get a chance to add AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

Comment: Just checked it, the handler applications are there.... When running 'sudo apachectl -t' to check the code I get the following message: "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using K-MacBook-Pro.local for ServerName
Syntax OK." Not sure what to do next...

Comment: I just changed the ServerName to "localhost" and am not getting any more error messages, but the .php files still don't open correctly... (They still only show the source code)

Comment: Sorted! Turned out I was using the wrong URL. Should have been http://localhost/~username/test.php. What I was originally doing was Browser -> File (Which only prints out the content of a file). The way I'm doing it now is Browser (sends request to) > Apache Server (which reads and interprets the php file and responds) > Browser (reads response and displays interpreted php).